# Running Python Web Server

Tags: python, web, flask

I am using python with Flask framework. As you may know that when you run the script, It will run in foreground. Like this:

```
python hello.py
 * Running on http://localhost:5000/
```

How can I run a python web server to run python script in background like what Apache Web Server does.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you can use "supervisor" to run it in background. its config is simple.

Comment: @xiaohen I mean running as a web server and not just running one command in background.

Comment: I think you can find the answer at https://sonnguyen.ws/run-a-flask-application-in-nginx-uwsgi/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is the web server process to detach from your terminal so you can keep using the terminal, then just send it to the background (like any other command):

```
python hello.py &
```

Or use more detailed output redirection:

```
python hello.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But note that (as stated in Fask documentation as well) Flask's default web server is not written for production and is meant to be used for development. Other WSGI servers (like Apache with mod_wsgi, Gunicorn, etc.) are suggested for production environment.

Apache is easier to manage on production server since most distro packages provide scripts to start/stop/monitor the Apache process. So all your need to do is install/enable `mod_wsgi` and [configure](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) the server to run your app.

[Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) is easy to [start with](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn).

I'll include samples to run the app in question using both Gunicorn and Apache, however please note that these samples are not the best configurations for a production environment.

### Gunicorn

Assuming you have your hello.py file module, and the Flask object is stored in a variable named `app`, you can run the app by running:

```
sudo pip install gunicorn
gunicorn --daemon --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 hello:app
```

Now this process is detached from your terminal (--daemon option). 
The above command starts gunicorn listening on a non-privileged port (8000). If you want to listen on a privileged port (like 80), you can drop privileges for worker processes:

```
sudo gunicorn --daemon --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --user www-data --group www-data hello:app
```

However if you need to have more control over the process, a process management tool like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [Perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/) can help.

### Apache mod_wsgi

If you're more convenient with Apache, install and enable `mod_wsgi`, then add a VirtualHost to point to your application.

Here is a sample config for the app and Apache configurations to run it.

Say we have `hello.py` where we have the Flask app, so save it to a proper place (and provide proper permissions). Here for example we use */var/www/myapp* but it's just for simplicity.

```
# file: /var/www/myapp/hello.py
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello!"
```

Note that the Flask object is stored in `application` variable, since `mod_wsgi` looks for the WSGI app object named `application` in the specified module.

Then install and enable `mod_wsgi`, as an example on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

Now add a VirtualHost to point to your WSGI app.

```
# file: /etc/apache2/sites-available/101-myapp.conf
<Directory /var/www/myapp>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp
        WSGIDaemonProcess www-data processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup www-data
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/hello.py
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now enable the host:

```
sudo a2ensite 101-myapp
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Note in the above example, I used *myapp.local* as the ServerName, so you'd need to change it to a name that can be resolved with DNS (or add *myapp.local* to your */etc/hosts* if you're testing on your devbox).

Flask deployment [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) provides more details regarding installing required modules or using *virtualenv* to run the app.

See [mod_wsgi](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/) docs for more details.

Both of the above solutions can be used to run other WSGI apps, not just the ones using Flask.

Comment: Good point. Flask is not(yet) for production. I guess I have to change my web framework to Django which is for production usage, right?

Comment: Flask as a web framework is ready for production and (in my perspective) is a great framewok. However it's not the role of the web framework to run the app in production. That is the role of a WSGI server. Most web frameworks provide a web server for development purposes, but that's just for convenience. I know Django also provides a server, but I'm not sure about if even that server is suitable for production (I'm guessing not). The point is a production ready WSGI server should be used to run the app, regardless of the framework that the app is written in.

Comment: I have use it but it will only show my Python codes in the browser! What is wrong?

Comment: Which one did you try and did not work, Apache or Gunicorn? I'm guessing it's Apache, and I'm guessing you've missed one of the steps. Did you restart Apache after installing mod_wsgi and configured a VirtualHost to use your Python module as WSGIScriptAlias? It shouldn't be showing you the Python source code if you've configured mod_wsgi to call your code. But If you just call a URL that maps to you're Python code, then that might be the reason for showing the source code instead of running it.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]
I misread the question. I thought you wanted a production ready server, but in case you're still in the testing phase, I normally use [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (here's [a tutorial](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)). In any case it's really good to learn screen, since it will come in handy in a lot of server related tasks.
[/EDIT]

I just set up a production server for flask using nginx and uwsgi using [this tutorial](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/). Assuming you're on Ubuntu 14.04, it's basically:

first install nginx:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

check if nginx is running by going to the ip-address in the browser and checking if you see the nginx welcome screen.

Then install uwsgi:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python python-dev
pip install uwsgi
```

remove the default nginx config:

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

create an nginx config file for you website called something like yourwebsite_nginx.conf (adjust the path to point to your website folder):

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/yourwebsite/yourwebsite_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

symlink this file and restart nginx:

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/yourwebsite/yourwebsite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
sudo service nginx restart
```

configure uwsgi to create the .sock file to which you point in the nginx config (`/var/www/yourwebsite/yourwebsite_uwsgi.sock`). Create a  file in `/var/www/yourwebsite/yourwebsite_uwsgi.ini` for this, containing:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/yourwebsite

#python module to import
app = yourappfile  # yourappfile should have the name of the file in which you do the `app = Flask(__name__)`
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv  # This should point to your virtualenv python install
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/yourwebsite/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app  # This is normally `app`
```

The start uwsgi:

```
uwsgi --ini /var/www/yourwebsite/yourwebsite_uwsgi.ini
```

This is it in a nutshell. But check the tutorial I linked to above, it explains things in slower, easier steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) for deploying your application using Apache and mod_wsgi. There's also an additional [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/99/) that someone wrote who mentioned that the Flask docs didn't work perfectly for them.

Comment: Can we run Python script in Apache with mod_wsgi ?

Comment: Yes, you can. The first documentation link describes how to do that for Apache.